# SKTileSet tile variant access in code

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sktilemapnode

I currently have a TileSet with two variants: Poison and NotPoison. I want these variants to react differently to being clicked, and I also want to iterate over individual rows and columns of my TileMap to count the number of "Poison" tiles in that row/column. I implemented it in this way because this tile type takes up a certain area of the tileMap. How can I access the specific variant in the code? Is it possible to alter the behavior between variants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add userData in the Tileset, by clicking on the image `Poison` and creating a `userData` item with key and value e.g. 'isPoisonKey' with value 1 and dataType boolean. Then in your `gameScene.swift` code you can check if a tile has this userData.

This example iterates through every column / row in a `SKTileMapNode` named `background` and prints to the debug console each time it finds a key `isPoisonKey` with a value of `true`

```
var backgroundLayer: SKTileMapNode!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    guard let backgroundLayer = childNode(withName: "background") as? SKTileMapNode else {
        fatalError("Background node not loaded")
    }

    self.backgroundLayer = backgroundLayer

    for row in 0..<self.backgroundLayer.numberOfRows {
        for column in 0..<self.backgroundLayer.numberOfColumns {
            let backgroundTile = self.backgroundLayer.tileDefinition(atColumn: column, row: row)
            let isPoison = backgroundTile?.userData?.value(forKey: "isPoisonKey")

            if let countNode = isPoison as? Bool {
                // Code here
                if countNode {
                    print(countNode)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is happening when you execute "self.backgroundLayer = backgroundLayer?"

Comment: That assigns the `SKTileMapNode` you've created in the `sks` file to a variable so that it is accessible in the swift code.